# Why doesn't typescript allow me to call the same variable name across multiple files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, variables, namespaces

My directory in question has multiple files that all call the same API 'got' and store it in the same variable 'got'

```
const got = require('got');
```

However, this causes a red bar underneath the got variable accompanied by an error message warning me that the variable was called in another file. My novice understanding of Node is that files scope all global variables in it so why does Typescript make a fuss about it?

To remedy in the meantime, I have been using namespaces (which admittedly I'm new to) which just removes the error bars. The code also compiles just fine without namespaces. Is this intended behaviour and what is the best practice way to skirt around it?

Edit: I got to playing around and finally got import/export syntax working. Turns out typescript doesn't consider module.exports and require good as a sign the current file is a module. Simply including import or export in the file makes it a module and these namespace clashes go away!

Answer (score 6):

Try adding empty export to any of the files as `export {}`

The export {} statement indicates that the file is an ES module. In TypeScript, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered to be a module.
Without top-level import or export declarations, the file gets treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and to other modules). This is what causes the name clash between our name variable and the name variable declared in TypeScript global typings.

link: https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/typescript-cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable/

```
// a.ts
const SOME_VAR = 'SOME_VAR';
```

```
// b.ts
const SOME_VAR = 'SOME_VARR'; // throws 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable' error
export {}; // ✅ now variable declared successfully
```